# add time delay to animate and redirect to next image

Tags: jquery, css, css-animations, animate.css

I have used animate.css for animation
how to add time delay so that it animates for few milliseconds and redirect slowly to the next page directed

```
<div class="row-fluid" id="animatetransport">
        <div id="industry" class="leftbg  col-sm-6 col-xs-6" style="height: 100%">
            <div class="imgwrapperleft">
                <h1 id="industry" class="text-center">INDUSTRY</h1>
                <!--<a href="industry/index.html"> <img src="images/factory.png" class="img-responsive"></a>-->
            </div>
        </div>
        <img src="images/logo.png" class="logo">
        <div class="rightbg col-sm-6 col-xs-6" style="height: 100%; ">
            <div class="imgwrapperright">
                <h1 id="transport" class="text-center">TRANSPORTATION</h1>
                <!--<a href="industry/index.html"><img src="images/excavator.png" class="img-responsive"></a>-->
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#transport").click(function(){
        /*alert("The paragraph was clicked.");*/
        $('#animatetransport').addClass( "animated slideInLeft" ).delay( 8000 );
        window.location.href = "industry/index.html";

        });
        });
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#industry").click(function(){
        /*alert("The paragraph was clicked.");*/
        $('#animatetransport').addClass( "animated slideInLeft" );
        window.location.href = "industry/index.html";

        });
        });
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `setTimeout` for this purpose.

```
$('#animatetransport').addClass( "animated slideInLeft" );
setTimeout(function() {
  window.location.href = "industry/index.html";
}, 8000);
```

Comment: Glad to help :)

Answer (score 0):

if you put your `window.location.href` change into a setTimeout it will be delayed by the number of miliseconds specified.

`setTimeout(function(){ window.location.href = "industry/index.html"}, 500);`